# Traefik error loading static files using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, traefik

### Summary

I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy for docker containers. However whenever I'm not able to render the react page because the static files doesn't get loaded through `traefik`,but if instead I access it using an exposed port (not using `traefik`) it works just fine.

Additionally the proxy is working fine because there is an api that can be accessed without errors.

### Configuration

Docker-compose

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2.0
    ports:
      - "${FRONT_HTTP_PORT:-80}:80"
      - "${TRAEFIK_PORT:-8080}:8080"
    environment: 
      - TRAEFIK_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_EXPOSEDBYDEFAULT=false
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER=true
      - TRAEFIK_PROVIDERS_DOCKER_NETWORK=traefik01
      - TRAEFIK_API_INSECURE=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_FRONT=true
      - TRAEFIK_ENTRYPOINTS_FRONT_ADDRESS=:${FRONT_HTTP_PORT:-80}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    security_opt:
      - label:type:docker_t

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "999:80"
    expose:
      - 80
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.entrypoints=front"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.rule=PathPrefix(`/frontend{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=frontend-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/frontend"
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.priority=2"
      # - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.priority=1"
      # - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ctf.itasahobby.com"
    stdin_open: true

  api:
    build: ./api
    expose: 
      - 80
    links:
      - database
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.entrypoints=front"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=PathPrefix(`/api{regex:$$|/.*}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=api-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.api-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/api"
      - "traefik.http.routers.api.priority=2"

  database:
    build: ./database
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: testnetwork
```

React Dockerfile

```
# Frontend (react) Dockerfile
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV PORT 80

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### Images

Here is a picture of the error using the proxy.
[image: Not working]
Without using the proxy works.
[image: Working]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I was applying the following middleware to the react app:

```
      - "traefik.http.routers.frontend.middlewares=frontend-stripprefix"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.frontend-stripprefix.stripprefix.prefixes=/frontend"
```

So even I setted the base url correctly all requests that the app was receiving had "/frontend" stripped from the url and ended up returning the base `index.html` which cause the error.